# Does Caffe's PythonLayer support GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, caffe

Is it possible for the forward and/or backward pass of a Caffe `PythonLayer` to access the GPU?

This question was recently ask here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5286

Answer (score 2):

### Update

This is possible with the merging of the [Pull Request 5904](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5904).

### Before PR 5904

From the [Caffe-Users mailing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/ufpGi3VviVA) and the referenced pull request [2102](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2102),
it appears that (as of this writing), Caffe does not support passing GPU data between custom Python layers. Since `PythonLayer` is full Python, it can access the GPU. It would just require data to be copied between the CPU and GPU multiple times.

Comment: It's still possible to use the GPU from a Python layer. See py-faster-rcnn repo that is doing this through a layer-external config key: https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/fast_rcnn/nms_wrapper.py